# Table name placment in tabular (\documentclass = IEEEtran conference )

Tags: tables, spacing, captions, ieeetran

I'm using the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference, letterpaper]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
        \begin{table}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
                \hline 
                Algorithm  & Space  & Query / Update time & Some other metric   \tabularnewline
                \hline 
                \hline 
                A  & 1  & 1  & 11  \tabularnewline
                \hline 
            \end{tabular}   
            \caption{Why like this?}
        \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

and am getting the following result:

[image]

Notice that the top of "TABLE I" intersects with the above `\hline`.

> **How can I make the "TABLE I" go down a bit so it won't intersect with the table?**

Comment: Usually a table caption has to go *above* the table. Do you really have to put it below?

Comment: @Bernard - I prefer so, yes. Haven't noticed a problem with this when using different document classes.

Comment: The class is designed to have table captions *above* tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
\makeatletter
\def\@IEEEtablestring{figure}
\makeatother
```

In this way you are using the same definition of spaces for tables as for figures.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to put `\usepackage{subcaption}` after the `\documentclass...` to produce this:

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference, a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
%...
```

The result:
[image]